# Key-value-order-dependent \includegraphics error: ! Package graphics Error: Division by 0

Tags: graphics, errors

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[angle=180,width=10cm,height=1cm]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

produces the following error

```
! Package graphics Error: Division by 0.

See the graphics package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.148 ...0,width=10cm,height=1cm]{example-image-a}

?
```

Is this expected? If so, why? If not, why does it happen?

This is not originally my question. One of my students asked it and I could not answer beyond suggesting the use of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=1cm,angle=180]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

which compiles as expected.

Comment: I actually meant to search rather than asking, necessarily, but the only way I know to search effectively is to pretend to be asking a question. I accidentally submitted it by pressing enter, I guess, at the wrong moment. However, this is the question I would have wanted to ask if I couldn't find the answer, which I haven't so far. The hopeful looking match turned out to concern a missing file. However, there's a deleted answer there mentioning LyX's `rotate after scaling` option (I think). Is this the answer? To always scale before rotating?

Comment: If `angle=180` is performed first, the rotated image has zero height, just depth.  Specifying a `height=` parameter afterwards tries to scale the zero height image to the specified height, which can not be done from a zero height starting point.  Changing the order of the process avoids that particular problem.  For example, try `x\includegraphics[angle=180,width=10cm]{example-image-a}` and you will see the resultant image is all depth (below the `x`), no height.  I fixed this situation with my `scalerel` package when trying to `\scalerel` something totally below the baseline (same error).

Comment: (continued) My mention of `scalerel` is only to point out that I recently came across this `graphicx` error and had to figure out the source of it when trying to use `graphicx` tools on a below-baseline object.  I recently released a package fix to avoid the issue.

Comment: @cfr: Since the height turns to 0, you can use `totalheight=1cm`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks. That is really helpful. It also makes me feel slightly better about not knowing the answer, since you suggest that you didn't find the cause immediately obvious.  ;)

Comment: Indeed, `\scaleto{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}}{2ex}` will break the pre `2016-12-29` version of `scalerel`, but works with the latest version.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I don't really think that's a solution I could have offered today. It just would have been good to have an explanation of why it worked to rotate last. Maybe this should have been obvious to me, but it wasn't :(.

Answer (score 2):

The question was resolved in comments.  But here, (5 months later) I lay out visually what the issue was for the other readers, by way of MWE.  In the first line, I plot the baseline and two images rotated 90 degrees about their center.  The first is specified to `height=1cm`, while the second is specified to `totalheight=1cm`, where `totalheight` constitutes the sum of the height plus the depth of the image.

What we take away here is that `height=1cm` refers explicitly to the amount of height above the baseline.  And this is the key to understanding the failure of the OP's invocation, `\includegraphics[angle=180,width=10cm,height=1cm]{example-image-a}`.  The directives are processed left to right.  An image rotated 180 degrees, as shown in the 2nd line of the output, has zero height above the baseline.  Thus, there is no finite level of scaling that can occur to make the resultant image exhibit a `1cm` elevation above the baseline.  This attempt to scale without bound is what brings about the Division by 0 error.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\leavevmode\rlap{\rule{3in}{.5pt}}
\raisebox{.4cm}{1cm}%
\rule{1pt}{1cm}
\includegraphics[origin=center,angle=90,height=1cm]{example-image}
\includegraphics[origin=center,angle=90,totalheight=1cm]{example-image}
\rule[-7.2pt]{1pt}{1cm}%
\raisebox{.25cm}{1cm}
\bigskip

Height is zero

\leavevmode\rlap{\rule{3in}{.5pt}}
\includegraphics[angle=180,width=1cm]{example-image}

scaling it by $\infty$\\ still has zero height
\end{document}
```

[image]